# AngularJS Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] error after using gulp-concat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat

I have an Angular app that works if I load in all of the scripts manually, but fails once I try to use gulp-concat to use a single bundle.js file.

I'm loading AngularJS and jQuery in from a CDN before the rest of the scripts, but I do use ngSanitize and ngRoute from local files. As I said, everything works when I load them all separately.

jQuery seems to work(some jQuery related tasks work on the site when using the bundle.js script).

I'm getting 2 console errors in this order:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function`
and `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`.

I checked the line where it says the first error occurs in the bundle.js file, but I'm not even using a `.ready()` there, so I'm kind of confused.

I've tried loading in the ngSantize and ngRoute modules from a CDN also instead of using them locally but that didn't work. I already read here on SO to try using angular-resource, which I tried, but didn't have any luck. I'm also using gulp-order to make sure everything is loaded in the same order as I loaded it manually.

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var order = require("gulp-order");

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./js/**/*.js')
  .pipe(order([
    "main.js",
    "others/*.js",
    "controllers/*.js",
    "modules/*.js",
    "directives/*.js",
    "filters/*.js"
  ]))
  .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

When I examine the bundle.js file, everything appears to be there, and in the same order as if I had loaded it all manually.

Is there something else I need to do?

**UPDATE**

I also tried downloading the latest minified versions of AngularJS and jQuery and bundling them into my bundle.js file, but am getting the same `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` error. The same result when I do NOT include them in the bundle.js but instead just call them before bundle.js.

Comment: You should also include dependencies such as angular, jquery file. Gulp does not get cdn js.

Comment: @kazupooot Thanks for suggestion. I downloaded and put the minified versions of jQuery and AngularJS into the gulp-concat task, and had both of them added at the top of the bundle.js file. But I'm getting the same issue. jQuery at least seems to detect because Bootstrap works... if no jQuery is found then Bootstrap gives a particular error in console, and I'm not getting that.

Comment: @Chirpizard did you fixed the issue? I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp does not effect the string so in config.
Make the state and router provider to string as show in the example.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])         

// configuring our routes 
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {    
    $stateProvider    
        // route to show our basic form in login page
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
}]);
```